# jsf multiple custom validator messages for regex

Tags: jsf, validation

I need to validate two fields in a form: email and name. The email should match the patern a.a@x.x and the name should only contain letters.

I have the custom-faces-messages.properties with the message I need to display when the pattern is not matching.

> javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED = {1}: Validation
>   Error: Value not according to pattern ''{0}''

However, instead of {0} which displays the pattern in a pretty ugly way, I would like to display a custom text for every validation. Ex for name it should be 'Name can only contain letters' and for email 'Email does not match the pattern. Example a.a@x.x'

Is there a way to do this using the properties file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want a specific new message for every field? It does not seem possible despite `{0}` and `{1}` can be substituted.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have specific different messages .. is there any way to pass some parameters to the properties file or something?

Answer (score 2):

If your email and name fields are implemented as `h:inputText`, then you can use `validator` and `validatorMessage` attributes for that purpose. See [JSF VDL document](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/).

2nd (more complicated) way: create your own validator. I have own email validator and I call it in application like this:

```
<h:inputText id="email" label="#{msg.email}"
    value="#{registrationForm.email}"
    size="40" maxlength="80" required="true">
    <f:converter converterId="lowerCase" />
    <f:validator validatorId="email-validator" />
</h:inputText>
```

3rd way: check it in backing bean and display message which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to call this from your properties file. 
I do that way. create a message.properties file under properties package in your project. (my path is : src/main/bla.bla.bla/bean/properties/message.properties)

now;

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml edit this file. 
add those lines below

```
<application> 
   your.src.bla.properties.message (this is path to message.properties file)
</application>
```

(your.src.bla.properties.message) DONT change properties.message part as reverse.

and add this line to message.properties file :

```
javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.NOT_MATCHED="Your message comes here"
```

now stop and start your project because it may not be hot-swapped. 
you'll see your message in dialog, popups on the right corner of your screen.